# Vuetify datatable add totals row

Tags: vue.js, datatable, vuetify.js

I'm trying to add a totals row with this framework but seems it's not contemplated.
The only way I found is doing this, but the aproach is not correct...

```
<v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="desserts"
    :items-per-page="5"
    class="elevation-1"
  >
    <template slot="footer">
      <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th>150</th>
          <th>260</th> 
          <th>150</th>
          <th>260</th> 
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </template>
</v-data-table>
```

See this codepen to see the result:

https://codepen.io/slayerbleast/pen/KKKjWjP

The footer is like another table instead of reusing the same columns.

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You must use `body.append` slot for this purpose.

So it will be like this:

```html
<v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="desserts"
    :items-per-page="5"
    class="elevation-1"
  >
    <template slot="body.append">
      <tr>
          <th>Total</th>
          <th>150</th>
          <th>260</th> 
          <th>150</th>
          <th>260</th>
          <th>33%</th>
      </tr>
</template>
```